# issue with Data mapping from Big query and Azure data factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are importing Dat from big query to Azure SQL and using ADF pipeline and trigger . and sync on the daily basing  with trigger

Every day the trigger fails and the source mapping fails, We are using a select query to see the data and we are not using select * Query still, the issue persists.

Any help will be good

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: Be aware that BigQuery limits the maximum rate of incoming requests and enforces appropriate quotas on a per-project basis, refer to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#api_requests. Make sure you do not trigger too many concurrent requests to the account.